# css code to resize the image which is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to resize the image width and height through my CSS code. The upload image button is dynamic in my application. I cannot give the `id`/`class` name for the `img`/`div` tag through my code.

Below is the existing code for which I need to set the width and height of the image dynamically through CSS code, I cannot write inline css as these tags are created dynamically:

```
<div class="note-editable panel-body" contenteditable="true" style="height: 300px;">
    <p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,... " data-filename="xyz.png" style="width:550px;">
</div>
```

I tried the below CSS code, but I am unable to resize the image.

```
.note-editable .panel-body > img {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take into account that your image is within a paragraph as well.

```
.note-editable > p > img {
       width:200px !important;
       height:200px;
 }
```

!important on your width since it's already inline styled and you need to overrule that. That would do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important in CSS

```
.note-editable .panel-body img {
           width:200px !important;
           height:200px !important;
}
```

Comment: Its not effecting, may be if you notice my src of image , src="data:image/jpeg;base64,... " its converting image to base64 format, is that the reason its not taking the assigned width and height?

Comment: did you remove > from css rule? It should be in this way: .note-editable .panel-body img

Comment: Thanks all, the answer which i accepted had worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your CSS:
`img` is not direct descendant, so `>` is not working. 
Also you have to write your two classes together, like this: `.note-editable.panel-body`

```css
.note-editable.panel-body img {
     width: 200px !important; /* !important is not cool - just to overwrite the inline styles */
     height: 200px !important; /* !important is not cool - just to overwrite the inline styles */
     display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="note-editable panel-body" contenteditable="true" style="height: 300px;">
<p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/300/nightlife/" data-filename="xyz.png" style="width:550px;"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.note-editable .panel-body p img {
        width : 200px !important;
       height :200px !important;
```

}

Note that you are inside p tag so u need to add like above